# Parsing XML in C from a DTD and building a linked-list accordingly

Tags: c, xml, parsing, dtd

I'm trying to parse an XML file using C.

The DTD for this XML file is fairly simple. It's basically a bunch of key-value pairs, with support for arrays as well.

I've found XML parsers like Mini-XML and AsmXml, but they don't seem to support building a linked-list of the XML file based on the DTD. Is there an XML parsing library available that can read a DTD, and then convert the XML data into a linked list that I can easily search, access, etc?

Since this XML file is a bunch of key-value pairs, I'd like the XML parser to read the XML file, put it into a linked list, and then allow me to do something like `xml_lookup_key(xml_data, "Name")`, which would return something like *John Doe*, or `xml_lookup_key(xml_data, "lastNames")` which would return a linked list of last names.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: C doesn't have a "standard" linked list, so libraries can't support one. And a linked list is absolutely the least efficient lookup structure you could use.

Comment: A library can have its own linked list structure and return it.

Comment: Of course. But why would they. As I said, a linked list is useless for searches - most XML libraries that I use, like the excellent Expat are event driven to allow me to insert values into more sophisticated structures like hash tables. Or, if you really want slow, sequential searches, you can use libraries that hand you  a DOM.

Comment: @Neil: Well, I don't need to do a lot of searches, just a few lookups. Everything in this XML document is a key-value pair. So you might have key -> settingName, value -> settingValue(s). What I'd like to do is have the XML library parse the XML document -- based on the DTD / my schema -- and add everything into a linked list, so I can do something like xml_lookup(settingName) and get a linked list containing the value(s) for settingName.

Comment: I think you want two things - an XML parser and a simple key-value, in-memory database. You can find both for C, but probably not from the same source, so you would have to write some fairly trivial code to put the parser output in the database. This would al be much simpler in C++, of course :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) or [RXP](http://www.cogsci.ed.ac.uk/~richard/rxp.html)?

From my experience libxml2 is probably the best XML library available in C.